# case usage in mysqli for selecting and joining

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, case

Hello all I am having a simple problem while selecting some data from table and then joining the table with another table depending on the value of field in table 1

like i have **table1**, **table2** and **table 3**.
I want to

`select field1,field2 and then check the value of field 3 if field 3 has value = 1 then select field1,field2,field3 from table 2 and join table 1 with table 2 on field1 and field1 else select field1,field2,field3 from table3 and join table1 with table2 on field1 and field1`.

I now this can be done case but i am not so comfurtable with it please help me solve the problem ..

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Sonam did you tried something?

Comment: It's more a SQL problem, it seems, can you give us an exemple  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved using a `UNION` call:

```
SELECT t2.f1, t2.f2, t2.f3
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.f1 = t2.f1
WHERE t2.f3 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT t3.f1, t3.f2, t3.f3
FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.f1 = t3.f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.field1 AS t1field1, 
       t1.field2 AS t1field2, 
       CASE WHEN t1.field3 = 1 THEN t2.field1 ELSE t3.field1 END AS t2t3field1, 
       CASE WHEN t1.field3 = 1 THEN t2.field2 ELSE t3.field2 END AS t2t3field2, 
       CASE WHEN t1.field3 = 1 THEN t2.field3 ELSE t3.field3 END AS t2t3field3
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.field1 = t3.field1;
```